# Bean Type not being found in in Spring Test package

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit, spring-test

So here is what the current description of the error gives me.

*Description:*

**Field profileDoa in com.N2O2.Nitrouz_Studioz.controller.MainController required a bean of type 'com.N2O2.Nitrouz_Studioz.model.profile.ProfileDoa' that could not be found. The injection point has the following annotations:
- @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)**

*Action:*

**Consider defining a bean of type 'com.N2O2.Nitrouz_Studioz.model.profile.ProfileDoa' in your configuration.**

I'm sort of lost to why this error is happening as I've only been working with Java Spring Boot recently and still getting used to working with Beans. I've Autowired the Bean in the Test class but it's still throwing the same error.

Here's what I have in my test class and the Controller and ProfileDoa class.

```
@WebMvcTest(MainController.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = NitrouzStudiozApplication.class)
public class MainControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    ProfileEntity profileEntity;
    @Autowired
    private ProfileDoa profileDoa;

    private MainController mainController;
    @Mock
    private Model model;
    private boolean loggedOut = true;
    private boolean loggedIn = false;

    @BeforeEach
    public void intializeController(){
        mainController = new MainController();
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("Navigating to Website Correctly Displays Index page")
    public void loadsIndexPage() throws Exception {
        RequestBuilder request = MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/");
        MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(request)
            .andExpect(model().attribute("loggedOut", loggedOut))
            .andExpect(model().attribute("loggedIn", loggedIn))
            .andExpect(model().attribute("profileEntity", "Not logged In"))
            .andReturn();
        Assertions.assertEquals("index", result);
    }
}
```

```
@Controller
public class MainController {

    private boolean loggedOut = true;
    private boolean loggedIn = false;
    private ProfileEntity profileEntity;
    @Autowired
    private ProfileDoa profileDoa;

    @RequestMapping("/")
    public String home_page(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("loggedOut", loggedOut);
        model.addAttribute("loggedIn", loggedIn);
        model.addAttribute("profileEntity", "Not logged In");
        return "index";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/about")
    public String about_page(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("loggedOut", loggedOut);
        model.addAttribute("loggedIn", loggedIn);
        model.addAttribute("profileEntity", "Not logged In");
        return "about";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/signup")
    public String sign_up(){
        return "signup";
    }

    @GetMapping("/signUpForm")
    public String signUpForm(Model model, ProfileEntity profileEntity){
        boolean checked = false;
        model.addAttribute("profileEntity", profileEntity);
        model.addAttribute("join", checked);
        return "signUpForm";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/signUpFormError")
    public String signUpFormError(Model model,
            @ModelAttribute("error") boolean error,
            @ModelAttribute("message") String message,
            ProfileEntity profileEntity){
        boolean checked = false;
        model.addAttribute("join", checked);
        model.addAttribute("error", error);
        model.addAttribute("message", message);
        model.addAttribute("profileEntity", profileEntity);
        return "signUpForm";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/ForgotPasswordPage")
    public String forgotPasswordPage(){
        return "forgotPassword";
    }

    @GetMapping("/Forgot_Password")
    public String ForgotPasswordResponse(){
        return "forgotPassword";
    }
}
```

```
@Transactional
public interface ProfileDoa extends JpaRepository<ProfileEntity, Long> {

    public ProfileEntity findByEmail(String email);
}
```

Any help on this would be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `@WebMvcTest` you can write tests for your web layer. Spring Test will create a context for you with all beans that are required to test this slice of your application: e.g. classes annotated with `@Controller`, `@RestController`, `@ControllerAdvice`, filter, etc.

All other beans are not created for you as they are not in the scope of the *web layer*. In your case, that's any other bean your `MainController` injects.

You have basically now two options:

1. Mock the `ProfileDoa`
2. Use a real bean of `ProfileDoa`. This would require a database and more setup on your side.

For option one you can adjust your test like the following:

```
@WebMvcTest(MainController.class)
public class MainControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @MockBean
    private ProfileDoa profileDoa;

    private boolean loggedOut = true;
    private boolean loggedIn = false;

    @Test
    @DisplayName("Navigating to Website Correctly Displays Index page")
    public void loadsIndexPage() throws Exception {
        RequestBuilder request = MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/");
        MvcResult result = mockMvc.perform(request)
            .andExpect(model().attribute("loggedOut", loggedOut))
            .andExpect(model().attribute("loggedIn", loggedIn))
            .andExpect(model().attribute("profileEntity", "Not logged In"))
            .andReturn();
        Assertions.assertEquals("index", result);
    }
}
```

As I don't see any interaction with `profileDoa` in your `MainController` there is also no need to prepare any mocked method response. If you do however call e.g. `profileDao.findByEmail("mail@duke.io")` somewhere, you can use Mockito to prepare the result:

```
ProfileEntity databaseResult = new ProfileEntitiy();
when(profileDao.findByEmail("THIS_HAS_TO_MATCH_YOUR_MAIL")).thenReturn(databaseResult);
```

For option two, you can use a combination of `@SpringBootTest` and `@AutoconfigureMockMvc` to load the whole Spring context (all beans) and make use of `MockMvc`:

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoconfigureMockMvc
public class MainControllerTest {

  // no mocking required as _real_ beans are used
}
```

Here you might want to use e.g. [Testcontainers](https://rieckpil.de/howto-write-spring-boot-integration-tests-with-a-real-database/) to start a database for your test.

Comment: You are welcome. Can you mark this answer as accepted, so further developers will easily find this if they encounter a similar issue?